# Are there some default bordered backgrounds?

Tags: android, drawing, border, bevelled

I want to draw custom panel-like view with raised bevel border (Swing terminology). Are there some predefined methods for this? For example, is it possible to take borders from current button style? Or I obliged to create my own 9 patch or something?

Comment: i think you create your own nine patch image

Comment: If all you want is a bevel border, you may be able to do this with shape drawables, but I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 3):

A crude approach to this would be to make an XML drawable with a layer list inside and compose the structure of the button yourself. In my example you achieve the following button style.

[image]

And all the colors could be changed if needed to suit your style. I'm aware that the corners should be at a 45º angle instead of 90º but there is no easy way for me to show this here without some testing. The source XML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- The gray part of the border -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fccc"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- The black part of the border -->
    <item android:right="2dip"
          android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- The content -->
    <item android:left="2dip"
          android:top="2dp"
          android:right="2dip"
          android:bottom="2dp"> 
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffafafaf"></solid>
        </shape> 
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

As a further example of what you can achieve here, just by adding `<corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>`to the border shapes we can get a slightly less eye-sore style:

[image]

Or you can go for a different approach and avoid the raised bevel border, making it easier on the XML side and probably nicer. To achieve this kind of button:

[image]

The XML is just as easy as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>
    <solid android:color="#fccc"></solid>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff6f6f6f"></stroke>
</shape>
```